# Draw points and lines on an image and establish degrees of inclination

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Starting from an image loaded on my server, I would need to trace, for example, two points and identify the angle of the line that passes between the two points.

[Like this Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoIFI.png).

Unfortunately I'm not finding any way, do you have any idea how I can do it via HTML5 / PHP / JS?

Comment: Your question seems broad.  Do you already have the points as `(x, y)` coordinate values?  If so then see [How to calculate an angle from points?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9614109).  But if you don't have the points and are asking, *How can I recognize two points on an image, then draw a line between them on that image, then calculate the angle between them?* then that probably cannot be answered in a single question here, and would need to be broken down into smaller parts.

Comment: [Draw a line on an Image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12477364/3744182) and [JS Draw line between two or more points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17777362/3744182) and [draw imaginary path between two points and print image along that path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14557242/3744182) may also be relevant.

Comment: Thanks so much @dbc. It's just what I'm looking for.
How could I replace the "mousedown" functions to work even from a touch screen?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  You might want to ask a second question for that.